# PyQt close child window problem, infinite loop?

Tags: python, pyqt

While writing some code I have stumbled upon a problem that I cannot solve. I've stripped down the code to only show the problem. I've tried using MainWindow.close() but it closes first window.
Console error is:

```
self.close()
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Open new window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)

    def open(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Close new window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def close(self):
        self.close()   

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that points to this in the next part:

```
def close(self):
    self.close()
```

Since calling self.close() you are calling the close() method of the class that invokes returned self.close() and as you see it generates an infinite loop.

The other error is that PyQt does not recommend modifying the code generated by pyuic, the recommendation is to create another class that inherits from the appropriate window and use the class generated by pyuic as an interface.

Considering what is indicated in the previous part, the solution is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Open new window")

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Close new window")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def open(self):
        self.window = SecondWindow()
        self.window.show()

class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SecondWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tru it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Open new window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)

    def open(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Close new window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)     # - self.close

#    def close(self):
#        self.close()   

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]